I am not able to make the buttons in one line
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried width in line also but does not help



#outer
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
    display: inline-block;
}
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button></div>
  <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button></div>
  <div class="inner"><button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button></div>
</div>



